# Is this a correct way to say that I do not care much about money?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Is it correct to say "I don't weigh much about money" to mean that I do not care much about money? Is it awkward?

Comment: No it is not correct, and would merely puzzle any readers. In short, it's wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No it is wrong, it will only conguse readers, I have provided other alternatives, but they are usually used when *calling someone* that word, and not yourself.

["**cheapskate**"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheapskate) is a viable option here.

> a miserly or stingy person especially : one who tries to avoid paying a fair share of costs or expenses

["**Scrooge**"](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/Scrooge):

> a selfish and unfriendly person who is not willing to spend or give away money

["**Indifferent-to-Money**"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cnbc.com/amp/2021/04/28/7-money-personality-types-and-the-pitfalls-of-each.html):

> You rarely think about money (and just the idea of creating a budget makes you nauseous).
> In extreme cases, you believe that money is inheritably bad or evil.
> You feel strongly that money shouldn't influence important decisions in life.

So you can you are **indifferent to money**.

Comment: Why not just "I don't care too much about money".. you could even follow it with the last line, "Money can't buy me love" & you've nearly got a song ;) Cheapskate & Scrooge are the complete opposite of what the OP asked, & the last, whilst fine alone is badly twisted by the unusual definition beneath it.

Comment: OP accepted my answer because he felt it answered what he wanted @gonefishin'again. He would not have asked the question in the 1st place if he wanted I dont care too much about money as the answer

Comment: We can't really guess why the OP accepted a poor answer. Perhaps, as often happens, people just accept the first answer that comes along thinking it must be correct. BTW, I guess you completely missed the joke.

Comment: Surely a miser or a Scrooge cares _too much_ about money - that's why they don't want to spend it!